# Understanding Timestamp Values

Tags: postgresql

I am confused on what I have found on other posts and through documentation. What does 2023/10/21 14:33:00-06 mean?

Is this "2023/10/21 14:33:000000" ?

Comment: This your second question that could have been answered with just a little time with the docs.   [Datetime type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) *8.5.1.3. Time Stamps ... The SQL standard differentiates timestamp without time zone and timestamp with time zone literals by the presence of a “+” or “-” symbol and time zone offset after the time. ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 2023: Year
- 10: Month
- 21: Day
- 14: Hour(24/hr format)
- 33: Minutes
- 00: Seconds
- -06: Time Zone Offset

The -06 in the time zone offset indicates that this timestamp is 6 hours behind UTC. **Note:- the precision is upto seconds only.**